# legacy question (wd labs pi node zero), trying to ssh over usb

Tags: ssh, software-installation

I'm completely new to raspberrypi, but decided to have a go with a simple stand-alone timelapse camera setup. I needed lots of storage memory but not much computing power, so i got a new-old-stock wd labs pi node zero and THEN discovered that wdlabs have removed all the help resources for it, so here i am.

I've installed jessie lite with the "custom version of noobs" and i'm trying to get ssh over usb up and running. i've enabled ssh with a blank file named ssh in /boot and added "modules-load=dwc2,g_ether" to cmdline.txt with no problems, however when i add "dtoverlay=dwc2" to config.txt the pi fails to boot because it gets stuck "waiting for root device /dev/sda6".

Obviously it normally just boots from the pidrive without a problem and if i # out the line in config it boots fine again.

Anyone got any suggestions???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to use an obsolete OS and unsupported NOOBS following instructions for a different OS. Try a current OS.

Comment: Its pretty easy to put the RPI0 into USB gadget ether net mode..    The configuration on the machine your plugging into is less trivial.

For starters you have to tell the OS's to use a static mac address for the USB aged the default I found was its random.

I use netplan on on my Pi's for both the gadget and the host..    I'll share them if you want to see how I've done it.